# Benefit of using Lodash's has-method over Vanilla-JS?

Tags: javascript

After having a look at this example from the [Lodash-documentation of the has-method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#has):

```
var object = { 'a': { 'b': 2 } };

_.has(object, 'a.b');
// => true
```

I asked myself: **What's the actual purpose of using this method?**

Wouldn't be ...

```
if (object.a.b) {
    ...
}
```

the same and isn't more code too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vanilla JS, your code will throw an error if `object`, or `object.a` is undefined:

```js
const object = {};
if (object.a.b) {
}
```

Thus the lodash method.

```js
console.log(_.has({}, 'a.b'));
console.log(_.has(undefined, 'a.b'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And of course if you happen to have a key path as a string, it's handy for that too.

Comment: @CaptianPerformance: Ahh, I get it. You would have to write something like 'if (object && object.a && object.a.b) to be safe of an error. Lodash is indeed more convenient in that case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @michael.zech: I'd better used vanilla JS in the places, that don't need special libraries. The `if (object && object.a && object.a.b)` will work always, even 20 years later. Lodash may brake some code in inaccurate new version release, or just drop support of such methods - who knows what will be in the next 20 years...?